# What are the different types of camping for a beginner?

Tags: hiking, gear, camping, tents, winter

I am looking into the camping hobby no found  few different styles, specifically the shelter used in the outdoor.

So far I have learned that camping with a wood stove means it is hot tent camping, and regular tent, then there is tarp.

In this video this person had a tent and a floor mat plus a stove. https://youtu.be/9PcHQRzmcCM

Does that tent constitute as a tarp since it has no floor? And what would the floor mat be called?

---

Apparently the tent thing is called a lavuu.

Comment: The floor mat of a tent is called a *groundsheet*. There are lots of resources available, just google the title. For example [The Complete Guide to Camping for Beginners & First-timers](https://veggievagabonds.com/camping-for-beginners/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kinds of camping? You can divide it across many different axes. Probably more important than tent type is transportation type. Are you carrying everything on your back all the time, hiking? Or are you riding a bike? Is a tour company transporting your stuff for you from site to site? Are you canoing from site to site with the occasional portage? Are you driving from site to site? Are you going to camp in a new site every night, or stay in one place for a week or more?

If you have the luxury of not having to carry it all, you will probably choose a tent with a built in floor. (A tent with a stove in it, sometimes called a hot tent, enables winter camping. For a given trip you would not be choosing between a "tent" and a "hot tent", especially in warm weather.) If you are carrying it all you might choose ultralight equipment - not just your tent just also your pad, bag, and so on. Or to omit some equipment entirely, like sleeping under a tarp instead of inside a tent. If you're driving, you may take huge multi-room tents, plus a dining tent, folding chairs, a picnic table, and so on. Or you could hook a camping trailer to your vehicle and sleep in a real bed with a comforter, and cook at a counter with a sink!

There are plenty of questions here on the specific equipment you might choose, and why. I can recommend [Why shouldn't I buy an ultra light tent?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5966/why-shouldnt-i-buy-an-ultra-light-tent) as an example of some of the considerations in choosing equipment. This isn't just about discovering 3 or 4 categories of camping and then picking one.

Comment: Thank you! I now know how to ask more specifically.

Answer (score 4):

As a new camper, without any experience, the most important thing is to take it gradually.

@Weather Vane in his comment recommended a specific primer, and reading that or another primer is a good idea.  My husband and I did not read a primer, but we went with experienced friends on our first trip, who advised us on sleeping bags and packs.  They had a spare tent, which they loaned us. Clothing is pretty much common sense when you know the likely weather.

Based on that experience, we bought a small tent, a one-burner campstove, a guide book, some maps, a cooking pot, three Sierra cups, more comfortable boots, and freeze-dried food and took weekend trips.  (This was in the California Sierra.) We never stayed in a campground, but did not travel far, and hiked on trails.

The second season, we felt comfortable taking a two week cross-country backpacking trip, which taught us a lot about equipment.

I can't go through all the steps we took in our education, but I hope this gives you an idea of how to start. Backpacking is an art and a science as is judging one's capabilities.

As for your specific question about a wood stove, take a one-burner gas stove but **never** light it inside the tent.  Winter camping is a whole different level.

I just looked at your video, and although it looks like a lot of fun, and something to aspire to, you should not attempt such a trip except with experienced people, or until you know a lot about summer, late spring and early fall camping.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I will look into overnight stays for now.

Comment: This.  Novices should only go to into the backcountry in the company of experienced people.  Don't make more work for the search and rescue teams!